# Mirror remote directory locally and update remote on local change

Tags: linux, rsync, nfs, fuse

I currently have my source code on `machine A`, and I want to be able to access that source code from `machine B` and `machine C`

The idea being, I use one central point to store the source code, then I edit the source code from `machine B` and the source code is served via web server on `machine C` for testing

NFS just isn't cutting it, I save a file on `machine B`, and it takes 10-15 seconds for those file changes to show up on the web server (`machine C`)

Ive tried SSHFS and it performed a bit better, but SSHFS doesn't survive my computer going to sleep and is a pita reconnecting...

What I want is to have `machine B` and `machine C` maintain local copies of the files in a directory on `machine A` and when `machine B` updates or creates a new file, the updated or new file should be replicated to `machine A` and `machine C` somewhat instantly

Any ideas of any software out there that might do this? Im trying to avoid Rsync...

Comment: Why avoid rsync? And you should really be using Git...

Comment: rsync isn't as instant as I want, and of course I use git, its a lot easier maintaining one repo, rather than 2 or 3...

Comment: If you have git you could look into "git hooks" to initiate a pull when commits are done, for instance on receiving a commit, the server issues an `ssh user@remote git pull`, or you can also look into using Ansible.

Comment: ahh good point, seems like a bit much though for a development workflow, that would mean I would have to commit before each test/page refresh...